# Change Div Class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change Div class on click. What I'm currently trying to do:

I got this on my divs:

```
onclick"changeClass()"
```

and this is my function

```
function changeClass(){
    $("#test123").attr("class", "classname");
}
```

However it's not working. You should now that I generate many divs with Id test123 with foreach loop so that may be the problem but I'm not really sure

Comment: **id** has to be unique.  If you are generating div's with the same id, at most your code will change the first div in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `=`:

```
onclick="changeClass()"
```

Also, you need to specify which?

```
onclick="changeClass(this)"
```

Then in the code:

```
function changeClass(which) {
    $(which).attr("class", "classname");
}
```

Instead of all these, since you are using jQuery, you can do it in a simple way:

```js
$(function () {
  $("div").click(function () {
    this.className = "classname";
  });
});
```

```css
.classname {
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4">Test 4</div>
```

If you want multiple classes, it is always better to add and remove class.

```js
$(function () {
  $("div").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("classname");
  });
});
```

```css
.classname {
  background: #ccf;
}
.myClass {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2" class="myClass">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4" class="myClass">Test 4</div>
```

This way, it doesn't affect the previous classes.

Comment: This did it ! Thanks man, I will select your answer as soon as possible (6 minutes)

Comment: @Michael I am waiting... `:)`

Comment: @Michael Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays.

Comment: One more simple thing, when I do this some other divs are changing color other than divs with id of item. Can I somehow instead of `$("div").click(function () {` add something to apply this only for div with id of item ?

Comment: @Michael Change `$("div")` to `$("#test123")`. `:)`

Comment: hahah sorry for bothering you but now only the first Div is accepting change xd :)

Comment: @Michael Are you repeating `id`s?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick

> onclick
>       Type: script code
>       This event handler is called when the object is clicked.
>
> Example
>   < image src="hello.png" onclick="alert('Hi')"/>

As described on example, it should be written as `onclick=foo(args)`

```js
changeClass = function(){
  document.querySelector("div").setAttribute('class', 'black');
}
```

```css
.red {
background: red;
}
.black {
background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="red" onclick="changeClass()">
  lorem
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="changeClass()">click me to change class</button>
```

Comment: Mate, you have such a good reputation and yet, you don't explain stuff? What kind of attitude is this?

Comment: it's suddenly posted -)) i am editing on other tab -))

Comment: Okay buddy. From next time, please add some details on what you do.